Is a low taper haram without the intention of imitating kuffar
My parents have noticed a change in me and my behaviors in the past year and one of those changes is that I used to get a taper haircut. After a little research I ended up cutting it all short and now it’s been 6 months. My hair is now grown and my parents have said that I’m to hard on my self and that they want me to get a haircut for “young people” because they think that I am depressed since I’ve stopped doing things like these haircuts. Now ive been doing more research and I actually saw that tapers or fades aren’t haram so I want to make sure and get as much evidence as possible I don’t plan on having it this long but I just plan to get the same haircut but not as long as it used to be.
